# PhpStorm does not autocomplete JavaScript native methods or properties

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ide, phpstorm

I use PhpStorm, I've noticed that when writing JavaScript, the IDE won't autocomplete native methods or properties of variables whose type PhpStorm should know.

```
var checkButton = document.forms.addSeller.check;
checkButton.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.open("POST", "/seller");
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                console.log(response);
                var target = document.getElementById("seller_info");
                var image = document.createElement("img");
                image.src = response.logo;
                image.id = "seller_logo";
                target.appendChild(image);
            }
            else {
                alert("Problem!");
            }
        }
    };
    request.send("seller=" + document.forms.addSeller.seller.value);
}
```

None of the methods (`.preventDefault()`, `.open()`, `.setRequestHeader()`) or the properties (`.onload`, `.onclick`) were auto completed.

Settings looks fine as far as I can tell, but I hadn't found a specific JavaScript autocompletion setting.

Anyone knows how can I re-enable it? PhpStorm 100% **knows** which objects they are, because it does syntax highlighting and error reporting well, and when I <kbd>CTRL+Click</kbd> a method/property, it will open PhpStorm's internal syntax files on the correct symbol.

Comment: Please try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` | `Invalidate and Restart`. If it doesn't help, attach a complete sample project to reproduce.

Comment: if invalidating caches doesn't help, please attach your idea.log - there are might be some errors affecting the completion

Comment: @CrazyCoder: Invalidating the caches worked well. Please consider posting it as an answer, so that I may accept it and shower you with fake internet points and cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` | `Invalidate and Restart`, it usually helps in case of such weird issues.

Answer (score 0):

I know, that this topic is old, but I had the same issue in PhpStorm 2020.1. The support of JetBrains helped me a lot to solve this.

My problem was, that I used the typoscript-plugin (TYPO3). The file type ***.ts** was added to typoscript files and removed for typescript.

So I had to add the ***.d.ts** to typescript again (I still use *.ts for typoscript). Somehow intellij uses *.d.ts files for the code completion. At least for JS.

After that everything worked like a charm.